# SwiftUI: Why not possible to scroll end of the long text in ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui

Showing here a long JSON:

```
ScrollView {
    Text (
        self.outputData ?? "na"
    ).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}.frame(maxHeight: .infinity).padding()
```

But always only first part is visible. And can not really scroll. Text is cut.

Comment: I just ran your code and it seems to run fine. Maybe the issue is happening some where else? more context or a sample text would be good to test on. If you copy this snippet and paste it into any test view and use some random long text from Lorem you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

try using `ScrollView (.horizontal)`. The default is to scroll vertical.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON has *really* a lot of characters, like 100k or more, `Text` is not the best view: it tries loading the whole content, so it takes a lot of time (maybe that's why you see the text freezing on the first lines) and it truncates at the end.

You can use `TextEditor`, which doesn't have this problem: it loads everything, little-by-little while you scroll. As the name says, it allows you to edit the text, but it does that through a `Binding<String>`, so you only need to provide an un-mutable string using `.constant()`.

Your code would become:

```
ScrollView {
    TextEditor (text:
        .constant(self.outputData ?? "na")
    ).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}.frame(maxHeight: .infinity).padding()
```

Try it, I believe it could be a solution.